# Android Studio :invalid end of optional part at position xx in pattern proj.android-studio/app/libs/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]

Tags: android, android-studio

I got strange error when sync the project in Android Studio 3.1.1;sync failed all the time,and the error msg shows:

```
invalid end of optional part at position 54 in pattern /Users/xxx/Desktop/project2017/xxx/xxx（ssc) v1.4/proj.androidstudio/app/libs/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]
```

tried many ways,but the issue still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally,this is a low-level mistake.The project was pulled from my company's internal git rep. The local dir path I saved to contains an illegal chart "（ssc)",this is the reason of sync failed.